# Rough location of Wifi device using 2 APs

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, geolocation

I devised quite useful system of roughly locating where my wifi devices are by using signal strength from single AP. Basically, I know that when my phone is in bedroom - it's never more than -80 dBm.

Outside of bedroom, though, it's not that certain. On the other hand, having a second AP would help that - I could now tell if it's in the bedroom, living room, on balcony etc.

The problem is, my AP (Asus AC66U) only shows this information for connected devices, and obviously a device cannot be connected to 2 APs at once. Secondary device could be a Linux box or DD-WRT, though, and I'm wondering if additional capabilities of such box would allow to measure signal strength for non-connected clients?

Comment: You miiiiiiiiiiiiight get by with something in [monitor mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode) but it's far from a sure thing. Also, because the signal will bounce off walls and attenuate through walls, strength is not necessarily linear with physical distance.

Comment: I'll check what can I do with monitor. Also, I'm not looking for finding distance, but location - the attentuation for my bedroom, for example, is known :-)

Comment: Every device sends a broadcast probe request.  Every AP within earshot must respond.  Based on the RSSI/Signal Strength from the probe request, you could code up a nice locationing tool.  This idea may be overkill though for what you are trying to achieve.  Nonetheless, food for thought.